# draw only edges with labels pair

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to draw the graph (ladder track representation) as follows:
[image: ladder track]
i.e. without node shapes and with two edge labels: at head and at tail of edge.
What should I do to achieve this?
(14, 15 — nodes with two edges each)

Comment: could be impossible to do with Graphviz, but so easy in (for instance) SVG. Why do you require DOT?

Comment: I want to be able to draw graphs from under the `C++` code directly (by means of `boost::graph` library).

Comment: AFAIK boost::graph *doesn't* draw anything. It delegates rendering to Graphviz, *if* you define the appropriate import/export binding. To draw in C++, take a look to (for instance) [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost ugly solution (do edit if you can improve correctness):

```
graph G {
    rankdir = LR;
    node [shape = point];
    edge [minlen = 2, fontsize = 8]
    a -- b [taillabel = "1", headlabel = "2"];
    b -- c [taillabel = "4", headlabel = "15"];
    b -- e [taillabel = "3", headlabel = "5"];
    e -- d [taillabel = "6", headlabel = "8"];
    e -- f [taillabel = "7", headlabel = "14"];
    c -- d [taillabel = "15", headlabel = "9"];
    f -- g [taillabel = "14", headlabel = "13"];
    d -- g [taillabel = "10", headlabel = "11"];
    g -- h [taillabel = "12", headlabel = "16"];
}
```

which leads to

[image]